# Generate 5G compliant parity check matrix and save it to .alist file

Tags: channelcoding, forward-error-correction, ldpc

My aim is to try out the 5G LDPC codes by using the aff3ct library. This library needs the parity check matrix loaded from a .alist or a .gc file to create the LDPC encoder. I've been looking how to generate a parity check matrix that is compliant with the 5G specs, can someone orientate me on this topic?

Thanks a lot

Comment: many 5G codes are actually delivered with aff3ct, did you check its website? Other than that, the Kaiserslautern LDPC codes listing has a-list files, pretty-good-codes.org (which sadly is currently down) has alists, so do a lot of other websites. You really don't have to write down the alist file from the standards specifications yourself. Other people have done that for you.

Comment: also, quick google: (26112,17664) [5G NR alist](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xiaoshaoning/5g-ldpc/master/NR_ldpc.alist) (no warranties)

Comment: (other than that, IIRC those are quasicyclic (QC) LDPC codes, so reading up on how these are represented in a base matrix probably makes a lot of things clearer. [ETSI TS 138 212](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/138200_138299/138212/16.02.00_60/ts_138212v160200p.pdf) specifies the base matrices for these QC codes. The thing is, if you have a QC LDPC matrix, you usually don't want to use a naive representation of the code (i.e., you don't want to use an alist) to feed your decoder, as that would lead to very inefficient decoder structure. I don't know whether aff3ct has support for QC.

Comment: ah, I looked that up. It does.

Answer (score 0):

Aff3ct directly supports quasicyclic matrix definitions, so you don't need to expand the base matrix and generate an alist to parameterize your encoder.

See the documentation of the `--dec-h-path` parameter, and the `--enc-type` (esp. `LDPC_QC`) parameter.

You can thus directly use tables 5.3.2-2 and 5.3.2-3 from [ETSI TS 138 212](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/138200_138299/138212/16.02.00_60/ts_138212v160200p.pdf) in a .qc file as explained in the `--dec-h-path` documentation.

So, no need for an alist. If you, for some *other* purpose, need an alist, you'll have to implement the quasi-cyclic expansion. That's pretty straightforward, and even ETS TS 138 212 describes the process in 5.3.2 step 3):

> The elements in $\mathbf H_{BG}$ with row and
> column indices given in Table 5.3.2-2 (for LDPC base graph 1) and Table 5.3.2-3 (for LDPC base graph 2) are
> of value 1, and all other elements in $\mathbf H_{BG}$ are of value 0.
>
> The matrix $\mathbf H$ is obtained by replacing each element of $\mathbf H_{BG}$ with a $Z_c\times Z_c$ matrix, according to the following:
>
> - Each element of value 0 in $\mathbf H_{BG}$ is replaced by an all zero matrix 0 of size $Z_c \times Z_c$;
> - Each element of value 1 in $\mathbf H_{BG}$ is replaced by a circular permutation matrix $\mathbf I(P_{i , j})$ of size $Z_c\times Z_c$, where $i$ and $j$ are the row and column indices of the element, and $\mathbf I(P_{i , j})$ is obtained by circularly shifting the
>   identity matrix $\mathbf I$ of size … to the right $P_{i , j}$ times. >
>   The value of $P_{i , j}$ is given by $P_{i , j} =V_{i , j} \mod Z_c $ . The value of $V_{i , j}$ is given by Tables 5.3.2-2 and 5.3.2-3 according to the set index $i_{LS}$ and LDPC base graph.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had to expand the matrix from the BG myself. So where can I find the .qc file of BG1 and BG2 of the standard? I don't know how to construct the .bg from the Tables you listed.

Comment: The documentation of aff3ct I referred to describes the QC format. You literally just have to put the content of these tables into that.

Comment: Oh I get it thanks! But this are very large matrices, are these base matrices available somewhere already in this format?

Comment: I managed to construct the matrices and parse them to the QC format. So if I want to try to encode and decode using QC_LDPC, should I give that same H matrix to both the encoder and decoder?